# On 18.04, package "virtualbox-guest-utils" does not exist

Tags: software-installation, 18.04, virtualbox

In the past, I've managed to get the virtual box shared folder via the command on trusty and xenial boxes.

```
$ sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-utils
```

But now on the bionic version - the packages does not even exist yet.

So my question is, how do we share the folder on ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: You probably just need to run `sudo apt-get update` first. If that doesn't help, please [edit] the question to include the full error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`virtualbox-guest-utils` exists on bionic in the multiverse repo. Simply ensure you have this repository enabled.

```
om:~$ apt policy virtualbox-guest-utils
virtualbox-guest-utils:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 5.2.10-dfsg-6ubuntu18.04.1
  Version table:
     5.2.10-dfsg-6ubuntu18.04.1 500
        500 ssh://[my-server]/apt-mirror/mirror/us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages
     5.2.10-dfsg-6 500
        500 ssh://[my-server]/apt-mirror/mirror/us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/multiverse amd64 Packages
```

Comment: sudo apt-add-repository multiverse && sudo apt-get update